# Issues with JavaScript settimeout function

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JavaScript and cannot seem to get the setTimeout command to do anything. I know this has been asked many times before, but I have spent the last two hours looking at all previous cases of it and it still isn't working for me. Here is what I have got at the moment:

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var i = 0;
    function aloop() {
        document.write(i);
        i++;
    }

    function afunction() {
        if (i <= 12) {
            setTimeout(aloop(), 1000);
            afunction();
        }
    }

    </script>

    <form>
    <input type=submit value="Click me!" onClick="afunction()">
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me what I should do to make this work?

Comment: In addition to the answers, look into using a regular `for` loop.

Answer (score 4):

Pass a function to `setTimeout`, not the return value of a function call.

```
setTimeout(aloop,1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're *calling* your function instead of *queuing* your function.

`setTimeout(aloop, 1000)` **NOT**  `setTimeout(aloop(), 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't describe what doesn't work, but I'll assume you want the `i` to be written in 1000 millisecond intervals.

Do this:

```
<html>
 <!-- you're missing your head tags -->

<head>
    <title> my page </title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var i=0;
    function aloop() {
          // don't use document.write after the DOM is loaded
        document.body.innerHTML = i;
        i++;
        afunction(); // do the next call here
    }
    function afunction() {
        if (i<=12) {
                 //     v---pass the function, don't call
            setTimeout(aloop,1000);

      //    afunction();  // remove this because it'll call it immediately
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<!-- you're missing your body tags -->
<body>
    <form>
        <input type=submit value="Click me!" onClick="afunction()">
    </form> <!-- you're missing your closing form tag --> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your help. It's working as I want it to now.